# pgadmin connect to linux server - database

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to connect to linux server which has a ssh connection. Im trying to do the same with pgadmin but I dont see the sshtunnel option in my "New Server Registration" window.

THe only I see is,

1. Properties
2. SSL
3. Advanced

Comment: pgAdmin [version](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+OCxoxfwBgLVVdJ_VigP-EbRG8=RcxXQccVvS9x0vSQ9-ABVw@mail.gmail.com)?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure tunnel in SSH/Putty.

For SSH, follow below steps

- Click on Profile -> Add Profile -> Give a name for new SSH profile
- Profile -> Edit Profile
- Select the new profile -> configure "Host Name", "Username", "Port" configurations on "Connection" TAB.
- On "Tunneling" TAB -> Click "Add"
- Give "dispay name"
- Listen Port -> This will the local port of your machine, have like "8888"
- Destination Host -> this will be "localhost"/"127.0.0.1"
- Destination Port -> this will be "5432" or the postgres SQL server port.
- Save changes and connect to server

On PGADmin

- Configure connection with "127.0.0.1" IP and Port Number will be "8888"

Above configuration is for SSH Secure Shell software.

---

In case if you are using putty then kindly follow below steps

- On LHS Menu, Select "Session"
- Give Host Name, Type connection name in text box for "Saved Sessions" & click save.
- Without doing any changes, on LHS menu navigate to "SSH" --> "Tunnels"
- Configure "Source Port: = 8888" and "Destination" = "127.0.0.1:5432" (*assuming postgres server is running on 5432 port*) and click on "Add"
- On, LHS, Navigate to "Session" and click "Save"
- Select newly created saved session and click "Load", navigate to "SSH" --> "Tunnels" section and confirm tunnel configurations are saved properly.
- Open PGAdmin, and configure new connection with "IP = 127.0.0.1" and "port=8888" settings.

FYI, I faced issues in configuring tunnel with SSH. The configuration succeed but I never got my tunnel connection to work on Window 7. In XP it worked fine with SSH. For Windows 7 and onwards I am using putty for tunnel configurations.

Thanks.